# Function Vs Virtual Method in IBM ODM

Tags: ibm-odm

How Function and Virtual methods are different in IBM ODM?
When we go for Functions and when we go for Virtual Method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go as much as you can with Java mapping as it will be easier to debug when there is a probleme.

Use B2X virtual methods only in very specific cases, like the ones when you need to get an internal parameter like the engine (context).

Best
Emmanuel